# What is the alternative packages for R(android) to HarmonyOs and Displaymetrics to harmonyOS and some constants?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos, deveco-studio

what should I do with the constants which are causing some problem.?

```
      import static android.net.ConnectivityManager.TYPE_BLUETOOTH;
      import static android.net.ConnectivityManager.TYPE_DUMMY;
      import static android.net.ConnectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET;
      import static android.net.ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE;
      import static android.net.ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE_DUN;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this question? What type of problem? What do you expect and what is happening?

Comment: Same here. Your question title and question detail seem different. More details, please.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an alternative API in harmonyos, you should check - [Netcapabilities](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-references/netcapabilities-0000001054678960) class from package `ohos.net.NetCapabilities`.

It has the following corresponding attributes -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `NetManager` class and other related classes in the **ohos.net** package may be what you're looking for.

```
public final class NetManager
extends Object
```

[image]

It provides interfaces to manage and use data networks.

This class provides interfaces to activate and query data networks and bind NICs to processes, as well as callback interfaces to listen for status changes.

For more info, kindly check [docs link](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-references/netmanager-0000001054238959).